# Derivative of square-root Moore-Pseudo-Inverse

Tags: matrices, derivatives, pseudoinverse

I have a symmetric matrix $A(x)\in \mathbb{R}^{JxJ}$ indexed by $x\in \mathbb{R}^K$.

I'am interested in
$$\frac{\partial (A(x)^+)^{1/2}}{\partial x_k}$$
where $M^+$ is the Moore-Pseudo-Inverse of the matrix $M$ and $M^{-1/2}$ is the matrix square root.

I'm able to compute the derivative of the usual square root inverse of $A$, i.e.
$$\frac{\partial A(x)^{-1/2}}{\partial x_k}$$
via the eigenvalue decomposition and its derivatives. However, for numerical reasons I want to switch to the MPI.

I also know how to compute the derivative 
$$\frac{\partial A(x)^+}{\partial x_k}$$
given by
$$-A^+ dA  A^+ + (A^+)^2dA(I-AA^+) + (I -AA^+)dA (A^+)^2.$$

But I don't really see how I can combine these parts. I would be very grateful for any hints.

Comment: Did you try the chain rule?

Comment: My problem is somehow that I don't really "see" the chain rule of $M^{1/2}$ via the eigenvalue-decomposition. Could you be more concrete?